# Javascript text box

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

Hello I have inserted a text box by using the java script, beside to delete button symbol.

Now I have to implement some logic to that text box to save the text readed data. Please could you suggest me, how it is possible?

```
testTypeNode.Text = testTypeNode.Text & "" & _
    " <img src=""../images/delete_16x.ico""" & _
    " style=""text-align:bottom; cursor:pointer;"" alt=""Delete TestType""" & _
    " title=""Delete TestType"" onclick=""javascript:if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete? Any running tests will be aborted!'))" & _
    " {" & ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnDeleteTestType, "" & sequenceNode.Value.ToString & _
    WordSeparationChar & testTypeNode.Value.ToString & "") & ";};"" />" & _
    " <input type = ""text"" id = ""txtExperimentalStressdays"" name =""ExperimentalStressdays"" size = ""4"" title=""Please enter the Experimental Stressdays"" javascript:onfocusdown(/>"
```

Comment: could you reformat your code to a more readable code?

Comment: what do you want to save the data in?

Comment: I think this is one of the worst questions here, with one of the gretest chunks of code, ever.

Comment: All, Please find the updated code. Your help will be appriciated! Thank You

Comment: still not good enough. post your full code so we can try to guess whats going on.

Comment: Post the actual source code in your browser, not in your editor, if possible with example in http://jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 0):

ok. i'll take a wild guess here.
copy this code to **page.html** and tell us if it's something like this that you're looking for.

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function(){
            $('#btncopy').on('click', function(){
                $('#txt2').val( $('#txt1').val() );
            });

            $('#btndelete').on('click', function(){
                $('#txt1').text('');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<p>
    <div id="divform">
        <form class="myform">
            <textarea id="txt1">Here is the text the you want to copy.</textarea> 
        </form>
        <button id="btndelete">delete</button>
        <button id="btncopy">copy</button>
    </div>
</p>
<p>
    <div id="divclone">
        clones: 
        <form id="formclone">
            <textarea id="txt2">The text will be copied here.</textarea> 
        </form>
    </div>
</p>
</body>

</html>
```

### EDIT

Scratch that. I just saw your comment.

> Amit Bhargava, I would like to read the user entered text from text
>   box and save that into database. Please help?

Comment: Appriciate you for moving forward on my question RASG, But your code won't work for me.  Please see the above updated code again. Now Am displaying the code as it is in my VS. Thank You!   I can't change the whole code, becuase am adding an text box to the existing code.

Comment: I believe this link can help you: [ask]